# Remove field from sudoku

Tags: generator, sudoku

I have a generated Sudoku for example [this](http://www.thedailyaztec.com/content/uploads/Sudoku_5-10.jpg).
My question is which fields should be removed from it, in order for it to be solvable after that?

Answer (score 0):

write a solver, then:

```
backup=sudoku.copy()
loop: removeRandomField()
  s=countPossibleSolutions()
  if(s>1)
    return backup
  goto loop
```

Comment: Is my logic correct?
For a Sudoku to have only one solution everytime there are empty fields, there must be atleast one field where you can put only one digit. Either way there is going to be more than one solution.

Comment: yes. but there are some "extra hard" sudokus with more than one solutions to confuse the user